# Add LoginStatus control to ASP.NET menu

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to add the LoginStatus control as an asp.net menu item?
I was trying with below code:

```
LoginStatus ls = new LoginStatus(); 
TopNavigationMenu.Controls.Add(ls);
```

Thanks
Darren.

Comment: Do you want to show `LoginStatus` in the root node?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to place LoginStatus control on page with `Visible="False"`, setup its LoggingOut event and use this code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds last menu item with logout link.
/// Main menu is configured to use SiteMapDataSource.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void mainMenu_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem loginMenuItem =
        new MenuItem(
            LoginStatus1.LogoutText,
            "logout",
            LoginStatus1.LogoutImageUrl,
            ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(LoginStatus1.Controls[0], null));

    mainMenu.Items.Add(loginMenuItem);
}

protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // required by ASP.NET to pass EnableEventValidation on page as our composed link
    // will postback from other control not original LoginStatus
    ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(LoginStatus1.Controls[0].UniqueID);

    base.Render(writer);
}
```